# Seasonality in ARIMA models

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality

In eViews its is possible to use Census-X13 adjustment after which you get a new set of data. It makes modeling easier, but forecasting does not include seasonality. Does it mean that this adjustment is made just to see the development of the time series or you should transform the data back to seasonal after forecasting?

Can I simply include three dummy variables for seasonality as we do in deterministic models?